# Screen resolution not display correctly grid

Tags: c#, uwp

I created a simple application on my laptop with 1440x900 resolution and size of text,app 100% (setting the menu screen in the settings). when I run the application on my tablet with 1920x1080 resolution and 125%, the grid is not displayed correctly.
right:
[image: right]

wrong:

[image: wrong]

if my tablet I change the size of font,app in 100% or 175%, the grid is displayed correctly.

thank you

Edit:
This is the code xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"></RowDefinition>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="#F2F2F2" BorderThickness="0,0.1,0,0.1">
            <Line Stroke="#E9E9E9" X1="0" X2="400" Y1="30" Y2="30"  StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="6" StrokeDashCap="Flat" />
        </Border>

        <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="#F2F2F2" BorderThickness="0,0.1,0,0.1">
            <Line Stroke="#E9E9E9" X1="0" X2="400" Y1="30" Y2="30"  StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="6" StrokeDashCap="Flat" />

        </Border>

        <Border Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="#F2F2F2" BorderThickness="0,0.1,0,0.1">
            <Line Stroke="#E9E9E9" X1="0" X2="400" Y1="30" Y2="30"  StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="6" StrokeDashCap="Flat" />

        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="3" BorderBrush="#F2F2F2" BorderThickness="0,0.1,0,0.1">
            <Line Stroke="#E9E9E9" X1="0" X2="400" Y1="30" Y2="30"  StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="6" StrokeDashCap="Flat" />

        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="4" BorderBrush="#F2F2F2" BorderThickness="0,0.1,0,0.1">
            <Line Stroke="#E9E9E9" X1="0" X2="400" Y1="30" Y2="30"  StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="6" StrokeDashCap="Flat" />

        </Border>
       <Border Grid.Row="5" BorderBrush="#F2F2F2" BorderThickness="0,0.1,0,0.1">
            <Line Stroke="#E9E9E9" X1="0" X2="400" Y1="30" Y2="30"  StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="6" StrokeDashCap="Flat" />

        </Border>
```

Comment: Could you please share your xaml code?

Comment: Which tablet device have you tried? In my Windows 10 PC(10.0.10586), I just placed your Grid under the root Grid panel and tested it in these two resolutions, the results are all the same.

Comment: I noticed that on my tablet Dell venue 7140 with resolution 125 and 150 is not working properly, with 100 and 175 working properly. I tried to change the resolution even on my laptop and it's the same thing. both with Windows 10.0.10586

Comment: I found the problem: changing the color in black and changing the thickness is now displayed correctly.` <Border Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1"> </Border>`

Comment: Post it as an answer, and accept it so the post is closed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing the thickness greater than 0.4:

```
<Border Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="#F2F2F2" BorderThickness="0,0.4,0,0.4"> </Border>
```